# Photo not displaying in image view android

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

So last night i thought i had my app working, however, this morning the gremlins have invaded and have now made a function of my app not work correctly.

Basically, a button allows the user to take a photo, and have that photo displayed in an Imageview, then attach the image to an email.. It lets me take the photo, and it is still present as an attachment, but the preview in the image view is completely empty.

Can anybody see what is going on?

```
Hoon_Image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.CapturedImage);
        button_take_photo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_take_photo);
        button_take_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    f = createImageFile();
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });
public File getAlbumDir()
    {

        File storageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
                ),
                "BAC/"
        );
        // Create directories if needed
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            storageDir.mkdirs();
        }

        return storageDir;
    }
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name

        String imageFileName =getAlbumDir().toString() +"/image.jpg";
        File image = new File(imageFileName);
        return image;
    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST ){
                Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
                Hoon_Image.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                //OI FILE Manager
                filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                //MEDIA GALLERY
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                //DEBUG PURPOSE - you can delete this if you want
                if(selectedImagePath!=null)
                    System.out.println(selectedImagePath);
                else System.out.println("selectedImagePath is null");
                if(filemanagerstring!=null)
                    System.out.println(filemanagerstring);
                else System.out.println("filemanagerstring is null");

                //NOW WE HAVE OUR WANTED STRING
                if(selectedImagePath!=null)
                    System.out.println("selectedImagePath is the right one for you!");
                else
                    System.out.println("filemanagerstring is the right one for you!");
            }
            Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
            Hoon_Image.setImageBitmap(photo);
            Photo_Selected = 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found to what i was doing wrong - derp moment coming right up.

this section of code:

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST ){
```

it was just looking of ok result (which happened both for selecting a photo and taking a photo successfully) rather than first looking for the RequestCode.

rearranging the code to this worked:

```
if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST ) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
                Hoon_Image.setImageBitmap(photo);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've done for the image to be shown in the ImageView in Android is to use a method decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) that decodes the File object with a required width and height. Below is a sample code.

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "image.jpg");
        bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),
                600, 450);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    // Query bitmap without allocating memory
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    // decode file from path
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    // Calculate inSampleSize
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    // decode according to configuration or according best match
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    int inSampleSize = 1;
    if (height > reqHeight) {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
    }
    int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;
    if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) {
        // if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) //
        // If bigger SampSize..
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
    }
    // if value is greater than 1,sub sample the original image
    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't exactly answer my question though.

Comment: my code above was working the night before, and this  morning it isn't. i don't want to have to re-code my app if i can avoid it.